# ¿Cómo Filtrar búsqueda por Mes usando Scope en Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy utilizando laravel 5.3,  un scope para buscar y filtrar "Próximos eventos", puedo filtrar por nombre, provincia, mes y año.

Estoy usando Carbon para facilitar el manejo de las fechas. Para el tema del mes, buscar todos los eventos de un mes particular. Lo primero que se me ocurrió un  `BETWEEN` pero después pienso en los meses con diferente cantidad de días, sin contar que no se me ocurre como encajar el `BETWEEN` en el scope.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{

    if($request->nombre == "" && $request->provincia_id == "" && $request->meses =="" && $request->anio == "")
            return $query
                    ->where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now());

    //dd($request->all());
    return $query
                ->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$request->nombre%")
                ->where('provincia_id','=',"$request->provincia_id");
}
```

El `if` es solo para cuando el `Request` llega vacío devuelvo la lista completa que necesito.

El `Request` me trae: la cadena a buscar, el `id` de provincia, el número de mes y el año; todos los valores son opcionales.

El `WHERE` que necesito para buscar filtrar por mes iría en el segundo query.

Comment: ¿de qué forma pasas el valor del mes en el request? ¿Es un entero entre 1 y 12?

Comment: Si, pense que era lo mejor asumiendo que voy a comparar con una fecha, pero puedo cambiarlo si es necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la función de eloquent `whereRaw()` y `date_format()` de mysql recomendaría algo similar a:

```
$mes = substr("00".$mesABuscar,-2); // no habría problema si mes es de uno o dos dígitos

return $query->whereRaw("date_format('date', '%m') = $mes")
             ->losDemasWheres
```

**Edit2:**

Cidius, tomando en cuenta tu respuesta acerca del whereMonth, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{

    if($request->nombre == "" && $request->provincia_id == "" && $request->meses =="" && $request->anio == "")
            return $query
                    ->where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now());
    if(isset($request->nombre) && $request->nombre != "")
        $query = $query->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$request->nombre%");
    if(isset($request->provincia_id ) && $request->provincia_id != "")
        $query = $query->where('provincia_id','=',"$request->provincia_id");
    if(isset($request->fecha) && $request->fecha!= ""){
        $query = $query->whereMonth('fecha', $request->meses)
                       ->whereYear('fecha', $request->anio);         
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voy a proveer una idea rápida, no probada, la cual consiste en general la fecha inicial del mes y año escogidos, a las 00:00 horas y a continuación generar la fecha final que sería exactamente un més después, todo esto utilizando Carbon. Por último, usar el query builder de Laravel para obtener los eventos de dicho mes:

```
$anio = $request->anio; // asumo que el año del mes lo puedo obtener así
$mes = $request->meses; // asumo que este es el mes del cual deseo obtener los eventos

$fechaInicial = Carbon::createFromDate($anio, $mes, 1, 0);
$fechaFinal = $fechaInicial->addMonth();

// en el query builder
->whereBetween('fecha', $fechaInicial, $fechaFinal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Me choque con la solucion mas apropiada buscando en la documentación la funcion de whereRaw

Resulta q laravel eloquent nos provee de `whereMonth('Date', 'numero_mes')`

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $request)
{

    if($request->nombre == "" && $request->provincia_id == "" && $request->meses =="" && $request->anio == "")
            return $query
                    ->where('fecha', '>=', Carbon::now());

    return $query
                ->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$request->nombre%")
                ->whereMonth('fecha', $request->meses)
                ->whereYear('fecha', $request->anio);
                //->where('provincia_id','=',"$request->provincia_id");
}
```

Tengo un problema con esta solucion, cuando uno de los campos esta vacio, osea no pongo fecha, o provincia o año, la seleccion me da vacia